# Spark difference between maven Artifacts spark-core_2.10 and spark-core_2.11

Tags: maven, apache-spark

Does anyone know the difference between the two spark core artifacts?
Both support Spark up to version 1.5.1. However, I alawys end up with the same error when using spark-core_2.11 in my Java application and trying to connect to the standalone cluster(Spark-1.5.1) with the spark url (spark://masterIP:Port)

```
WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@192.168.188.20:7077] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated] 
ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[appclient-registration-retry-thread,5,main]
```

The Master also logs a compability problem in its logs:

```
ERROR Remoting: org.apache.spark.deploy.DeployMessages$RegisterApplication; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 352674063933172066, local class serialVersionUID = -5495080032843259921
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.deploy.DeployMessages$RegisterApplication; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 352674063933172066, local class serialVersionUID = -5495080032843259921
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:621)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer$$anonfun$1.apply(Serializer.scala:136)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer.fromBinary(Serializer.scala:136)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(Serialization.scala:104)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization.deserialize(Serialization.scala:98)
    at akka.remote.serialization.MessageContainerSerializer.fromBinary(MessageContainerSerializer.scala:63)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(Serialization.scala:104)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization.deserialize(Serialization.scala:98)
    at akka.remote.MessageSerializer$.deserialize(MessageSerializer.scala:23)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payload$lzycompute$1(Endpoint.scala:58)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payload$1(Endpoint.scala:58)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.dispatch(Endpoint.scala:76)
    at akka.remote.EndpointReader$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(Endpoint.scala:935)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
    at akka.remote.EndpointActor.aroundReceive(Endpoint.scala:411)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

When using spark-core_2.10 everything works fine.

Comment: The only difference is the Scala version I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That errors is due to a mismatch with the scala version.

Spark is compiled for both scala 2.10.x and Spark 2.11.x, if you want to use Scala 2.10, and of course if it is installed in your env you'll be needing the spark-core_2.10, and  spark-core_2.11 for Scala 2.11.

PS: At a certain point, I think it was also available for scala 2.9

Comment: I see. So Spark 1.5.1 only comes with scala 2.10? Als least that is what they recommend at http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

Comment: Not at all! But you might just scala 2.10 installed in your environment. Here is a tip, you can check every available version of all the spark libraries [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark). I advice you to always keep an eye on this when you are working with dependencies.

Comment: Well, but we only use the scala that is provided with the spark prebuild distribution, if I don't mess something up.

So when I want to use scala.xml.MetaData, I need to add the dependency scala-xml-2.11.0-M4. This means I need to download the spark source package and build it against scala 2.11 instead of using the prebuild? http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-for-scala-211
Is that correct?

Comment: I don't quite catch what you are trying to tell me. Another question, why do you need to use Scala 2.11?

Comment: In the first place I only run the java application using master="local" (from windows). After this I wanted to run it via eclipse on a standalone cluster (on linux). The application does some reading of xml and setting files in order to locate the data and the schema of the datasources that are on hadoop.
When I run the app, I encountered an error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/xml/MetaData" so I added the dependency scala-xml-2.11.0-M4, which caused the above error message.I think i don't need scala 2.11 at all because after I cleaned a bit up, it seems to work now

Comment: I used the folowing dependencies: spark-csv_2.11: 1.2.0, spark-sql_2.11:1.51 and spark-core_2.11: 1.5.1;  spark-csv_2.11 seems to cause the scala/xml/Metadata error when creating the JavaSparkContext. After seeting it every dependency to 2.10 its working now. Thank you for the help! :)